# How to find signal handlers definitions in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, coredump

I am currrently working on `"Creation of Postmortem data logger in Linux on Intel architecture"`.
 Its nothing but core utility creation. 
Can any body share the details about how the signal handlers for various signals(`SIGSEGV,SIGABRT,SIGFPE etc`) which produce `core dump` upon crashing an application internally implemented in Linux kernel.  I need to re-write these signal handlers with my own user specific needs and rebuild the kernel. It makes my kernel producing the core file (upon crashing an application) with user specific needs like showing `registers,stackdump and backtrace etc`.

Can anybody share the details about it....
Advance thanks to all the repliers:)

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to modify the kernel at all - the kernel supports invoking a userspace application when a core dump occurs.  From the [`core(5)` man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html):

> Since kernel 2.6.19, Linux supports an
>   alternate syntax for the
>   `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file. 
>   If the first character of this file is
>   a pipe symbol (`|`), then the
>   remainder of the line is interpreted
>   as a program to be executed.  Instead
>   of being written to a disk file, the
>   core dump is given as standard input
>   to the program.

Answer (score 1):

The actual dumping code depends on the format of the dump. For ELF format, look at the `fs/binfmt_elf.c` file. I has an `elf_dump_core` function. (Same with other formats.)

This is triggered by `get_signal_to_deliver` in `kernel/signal.c`, which calls into `do_coredump` in `fs/exec.c`, which calls the handler.

Comment: Hi Mat,Thanks a lot for your answer.I got your approach right from get_signal_to_deliver(). But my question is the one prior to that approach.i.e. how the signal handlers are internally implemented???.How the handlers are defined sothat they have some mechanism for handling each and every signal???.For example,if "segmentation fault" occurs then how the "SIGSEGV" signal internally generated. Further, how it is handled internally sothat a message comes "core dumped". Here, creating core dump file with specific size limits in "do_coredump()" is secondary part. If you got my ques, pls respond:)

Answer (score 1):

[LXR, the Linux Cross-Reference](http://lxr.linux.no/linux), is usually helpful when you want to know how something is done in the Linux kernel. It's a browsing and searching tool for the kernel sources.

Searching “core dump” returns a lot of hits, but two of the most promising-looking are in [`fs/exec.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/exec.c#L1926) and [`fs/proc/kcore.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/proc/kcore.c#L4) (promising because the file names are fairly generic, in particular you don't want to start with architecture-specific stuff). `kcore.c` is actually for a kernel core dump, but the hit in `fs/exec.c` is in the function [`do_coredump`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/exec.c#L1915), which is the main function for dumping a process's core. From there, you can both read the function to see what it does, and search to see where it's called.

Most of the code in `do_coredump` is about determining whether to dump core and where the dump should go. What to dump is handled near the end: [`binfmt->core_dump(&cprm)`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/exec.c#L2067), i.e. this is dependent on the executable format (ELF, a.out, …). So your next search is on the `core_dump` struct field, specifically its “usage”; then select the hit corresponding to an executable format. [ELF](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L72) is probably the one you want, and so you get to the [`elf_core_dump`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1871) function.

That being said, I'm not convinced from your description of your goals that what you want is really to change the core dump format, as opposed to writing a tool that analyses existing dumps.

You may be interested in [existing work on analyzing kernel crash dumps](http://lkcd.sourceforge.net/). Some of that work is relevant to process dumps as well, for example the [gcore extension to include process dumps in kernel crash dumps](http://people.redhat.com/anderson/extensions.html#).

Comment: Hi Giles, thanks a lot for your response.I got your answer.But you were mentioning about the implementation of core dump file and its secondary part of my question. But,i am seeking details about how it is generated???. See, for example,whenever a "segmentation fault" occurs in a program, internally how the operating system handles that signals and displays message "core dumped".In this procedure,there must be a handler defined for that signal(here SIGSEGV).So,how the handler internally handles that signal and makes role in generating core dump. If you get my question..pls share the details:)